# Sign with Googleplus in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, authentication, google-plus, google-plus-one

I have tried a lot for signin with googleplus but having following isssue

1) I have creat clietn id like below

[image]

2) my javascript code is

```
$('.test').click(function(){

googleapi.authorize({

        client_id: '753933765205-jjo73l76a1k1sh7dqstnr75975jgle06.apps.googleusercontent.com',

        client_secret: '3yDj5mOF_owMijnILG5gJYnS',

        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',

        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'

    }).done(function(data) {

        $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);

    }).fail(function(data) {

        $loginStatus.html(data.error);
   });

});
```

When i run my app with above code click button then as output 
scrreen1 ) it show google page
[image]

Then when click on Accept it Either it fire error or if will come with on code and say copy paste this code in app.

[image]

I have search lot but didn't find such helpfull.Please help me
If you need and more clear code then i can also send full demo code.

Please help me.....

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What happens if you set the application type to Android?

Comment: thanks for replay. but i have also tried that but its not working it says invalid redirection url

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the javascript API.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript?hl=es

And check this tutorial for the callback url.

http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery

Comment: thanks for answer. i have already seen this link. but actually its using child browser. and in latest phonegap child browser is deprecated. so we need latest code using inAppBrowser.